# material point method problem

Tags: algorithms

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBLnf.png)

Is there anyone can help me get the Eq.14 from above equations？ Why is a "+" in the Eq.14? I thought

using v(Φ(X, t), t) to replace V(X, t), then could get an equation like Eq.14 but without the first term.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Was the selection of [algorithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithms) for the (only) tag some kind of typo, because this makes no sense to me. I know next to nothing about this (some minor prior acquaintance around 1982 or so), but surely the tags [fluid-dynamics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluid-dynamics) and [multivariable-calculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multivariable-calculus) would be better?